# How can I load an XML document that references a DTD that defines custom entities?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I've got some sample XML that I receive as part of a data feed that I'd like to be able to manipulate with the [DomDocument Class](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php); but the XML feed uses custom entities, which seems to be causing issues. The XML does specify a doctype using the relevant processing instruction which specifies the location of the DTD files, but it seems that it is either being ignored, or not retrieved as it is specified as being a HTTP URI.

Is there a way to load the XML and ignore the entities, or do I really have to do a bunch of `preg_replace` calls first?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it out, but [this article](http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2009/03/adding-a-doctype-declaration-to-a-domdocument-in-php.html) seems to cover the syntax for letting a DomDocument object know about your DTD.  It looks like you need to use a

```
new DOMImplementation();
```

object to create your DomDocument object.

Comment: That seems to be more about creating XML, not reading XML from somewhere else?

Comment: It also seems to require PHP5, and the installation I'm working with needs to be compatible with 4.4

Comment: @Rowland: You'd read your XML in as a string, and feed to to the DomDocument object you created in the linked example, and then parse it using DomDocument.

Comment: Also, DomDocument itself is PHP 5 only, so you're SOL if you want to use it in php 4.4

Comment: @Alan [documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.domxml-open-file.php) certainly describes this as being available on PHP 4 though?

Comment: It's been a while.  There's a DomDocument that works with v4: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php and one that works with v5: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php